# Symfony GuzzleHttp Crawler cannot find all elements on the page

Tags: php, symfony4, guzzle, domcrawler

I am trying to get data from the amazon product page. But the search for the price always result in `The current node list is empty.` . The other elements like title are present in the result.

```php
            $jar = new CookieJar();
            $url = "https://www.amazon.com/Simple-Mobile-Prepaid-Midnight-Carrier/dp/B07XSQT4Q3";
            $client = new Client([
                'cookies' => $jar,
                'headers' => [
                    'Host' => 'www.amazon.com',
                    'User-Agent' => 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/42.0.2311.90 Safari/537.3',
                    'Accept' => 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',
                    'Accept-Language' => 'en-US,en;q=0.5',
                    'Accept-Encoding' => 'gzip, deflate, br',
                    'Connection' => 'keep-alive',
                    'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests' => '1',
                    'Cache-Control' => 'max-age=0',
                    'TE' => 'Trailers',
                ],
            ]);

$response = $client->request('GET', $url);
$crawler = new Crawler($response->getBody()->getContents());
$title = $crawler->filter('#productTitle')->text('Product Title couldn\'t be extracted', true);
$price = $crawler->filter('#priceblock_ourprice')->text('Product Price couldn\'t be extracted', true);
```

If trying to run this request with postman the price is present.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that price was not always present on the page depends on your location, after updating to Symfony 4.4 the problem was solved and it started to return `Product Price couldn\'t be extracted` instead of crashing.